# To set scale and precision of a auto calculated number using c#

Tags: c#, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have a method which auto calculates an amount based on user input. 
My requirement is to set the scale as 4 for that number. E.G if the amount is 49, it should return 49.0000. If the amount is 49.2412412414, it should return 49.2412. I have used Math.Round(), but it doesn't work for example 1. i.e. it fails to convert 49 to 49.0000. My sample code:

```
    private decimal getAmount(decimal rate)
    {
        decimal Amount = 0;
        Amount = 12 * rate;
        return Math.Round(Amount, 4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the Amount by `1.0000M` to get the desired result. Your code would be like:

```
private decimal getAmount(decimal rate)
{
    decimal Amount = 0;
    Amount = 12 * rate;
    Amount *= 1.0000M;
    return Math.Round(Amount, 4);
}
```

However, as stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in**
>   **arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be**
>   **revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is**
>   **applied.**

So, 49 is actully equal to 49.0000, but if you want a string representation of the value you can change your function to the following:

```
private static string  getAmount(decimal rate)
{
    decimal Amount = 0;
    Amount = 12 * rate;
    return Amount.ToString("#.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: I want it to be returned as decimal.  The first solution doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You mean you don't get the precision?

Comment: No. It is not affecting the number

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate between the numeric reperesentation and the string representation. A `decimal` will ignore any trailing zeros. But you can force the trailing zeros to be displayed if you convert the decimal to a `string`.

```
decimal amount = 49.0M;
var rounded = Math.Round(amount, 4);
string display = rounded.ToString("#.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // "49.0000"
```